# Can we always form a closed set from a given domain

Tags: general-topology

I have certain doubts regarding open and closed sets. So, anyone please help me.
Can we always form a closed set from a given domain (open connected subset of the complex plane), i.e. choosing some subset of it?

Comment: A single point is closed. Do you need other conditions on your closed set?

Comment: Can it also contain some non-constant converging sequence?

Comment: I am envisioning for some complex plane topology.

Comment: @hardmath Good point. I had assumed it was the complex plane (just confirmed by OP) due to the terminology "domain = open connected set."

Comment: @hardmath could please explain why is it not necessary for all topologies?

Comment: @angryavian: I will remove my "point" now that it is "closed". ;-)

Comment: The property that all points in a topological space form closed singleton sets is called [the T1 separation axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space).  This is weaker than the Hausdorff property (T2) that holds in all metric spaces such as the complex plane, and stronger than [the T0 separation axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_space), which see for examples of topologies that are not T1.  Any set is closed in its own subspace topology, so some editing of the Question would improve it to make explicit what topology is meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a closed subset with a non-constant converging sequence, you can do so (assuming the open connected set is nonempty) by picking any point $x$ of the open set, and choosing points in $B_r(x) \setminus\{x\}$ (the punctured disk centered at $x$ of radius $r$) while taking $r \to 0$.